# Where is the actual "sorted" method being implemented in CPython and what is it doing here?

Tags: python, c, cpython

Viewing the source code of CPython on GitHub, I saw the method here:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/bltinmodule.c

And more specifically:

```
static PyObject *
builtin_sorted(PyObject *self, PyObject *const *args, Py_ssize_t nargs, PyObject *kwnames)
{
    PyObject *newlist, *v, *seq, *callable;

    /* Keyword arguments are passed through list.sort() which will check
       them. */
    if (!_PyArg_UnpackStack(args, nargs, "sorted", 1, 1, &seq))
        return NULL;

    newlist = PySequence_List(seq);
    if (newlist == NULL)
        return NULL;

    callable = _PyObject_GetAttrId(newlist, &PyId_sort);
    if (callable == NULL) {
        Py_DECREF(newlist);
        return NULL;
    }

    assert(nargs >= 1);
    v = _PyObject_FastCallKeywords(callable, args + 1, nargs - 1, kwnames);
    Py_DECREF(callable);
    if (v == NULL) {
        Py_DECREF(newlist);
        return NULL;
    }
    Py_DECREF(v);
    return newlist;
}
```

I am not a C master, but I don't see any implementation of any of the known sorting algorithms, let alone the special sort that Python uses (I think it's called Timsort? - correct me if I'm wrong)

I would highly appreciate if you could help me "digest" this code and understand it, because as of right now I've got:

```
PyObject *newlist, *v, *seq, *callable;
```

Which is creating a new list - even though list is mutable no? then why create a new one?
and creating some other pointers, not sure why...

then we unpack the rest of the arguments as the comment suggests, if it doesn't match the arguments there (being the function 'sorted' for example) then we break out..

I am pretty sure I am reading this all completely wrong, so I stopped here...

Thanks for the help in advanced, sorry for the multiple questions but this block of code is blowing my mind and learning to read this would help me a lot!

Comment: `callable = _PyObject_GetAttrId(newlist, &PyId_sort);` this fetches the sort function (PyId_sort), then it's called lated in the code

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre But I can't locate the `PyId_sort` in CPython, where is it actually implemented? what is happening in other lines of this code? I would really appreciate if you could break it line by line... I am struggling to understand it :( I know it's a lot of work so even some lines would be useful. Thanks in advanced and sorry

Comment: This appears to be a slightly older version of the code. Now its `&_Py_ID(sort)`, where I believe `_Py_ID` is a macro defined to ease looking up attributes on objects. Essentially, all this code does is create a new `list` object from `sorted`'s first argument, then uses `list.sort` to sort it in-place before returning it.

Comment: Most of the code here is just boilerplate related to memory management and error detection/propagation. A pure Python definition would be something like `def sorted(itr, *, key=None): newlist = list(itr); newlist.sort(key=key); return newlist`.

Answer (score 1):

The actual sorting is done by `list.sort`. `sorted` simply creates a new list from whatever iterable argument it is given, sorts that list in-place, then returns it. A pure Python implementation of `sorted` might look like

```
def sorted(itr, *, key=None):
    newlist = list(itr)
    newlist.sort(key=key)
    return newlist
```

Most of the C code is just boilerplate for working with the underlying C data structures, detecting and propagating errors, and doing memory management.

The actual sorting algorithm is spread throughout Objects/listobject.c; start [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listobject.c#L2220). If you are really interested in what the *algorithm* is, rather than how it is implemented in C, you may want to start with https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listsort.txt instead.

Comment: Thanks! so where is the actual `.sort` CPython implementation?

Answer (score 0):

list sort implementation isn't there. This is a wrapper function fetching `PyId_sort` from there:

```
callable = _PyObject_GetAttrId(newlist, &PyId_sort);
```

`object.h` contains a macro using token pasting to define the `PyId_xxx` objects

```
#define _Py_IDENTIFIER(varname) _Py_static_string(PyId_##varname, #varname)
```

... and I stopped digging after that. There could be more macro magic involved in order to enforce a coherent naming through the whole python codebase.

The implementation is located here:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listobject.c

More precisely around line 2240

```
static PyObject *
list_sort_impl(PyListObject *self, PyObject *keyfunc, int reverse)
/*[clinic end generated code: output=57b9f9c5e23fbe42 input=cb56cd179a713060]*/
{
```

Comments read:

```
/* An adaptive, stable, natural mergesort.  See listsort.txt.
 * Returns Py_None on success, NULL on error.  Even in case of error, the
 * list will be some permutation of its input state (nothing is lost or
 * duplicated).
 */
```

Now it takes some effort to understand the details of the algorithm but it's there.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much! so is this the Timsort I talked about? or is this something else?